# Efficiently make a view of (or copy) a subset of a large HashMap in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I am trying to create a subhashmap from a huge hashmap without copy the original one.

currently I use this:

```
val map = hashMapOf<Job, Int>()
val copy = HashMap(map)
listToRemoveFromCopy.forEach { copy.remove(it) }
```

this cost me around 50% of my current algorithm. Because java is calculating the hash of the `job` really often. 
I only want the `map` minus the `listToRemoveFromCopy` in a new variable without removing the `listToRemoveFromCopy` elements from the original list.

anyone know this?

Thanks for help

Comment: I guess it depends on the relative sizes of things.  One alternative is `val copy = map - listToRemoveFromCopy`.

Comment: map.copy() is the same result :(

Comment: Ok, i will try it, thanks

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth minus operator does a full copy and then removes items which would be the same slowness already seen.

Comment: Did you try memoizing hashCode() computation?

Comment: @auryn31did you get what you need yet, or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, you need to cache the hashcode for `Job`** because any approach you use will be inefficient if you cannot have a set or a map of `Job` objects that operate at top speed.

Hopefully, the parts that make it a hashcode are immutable otherwise it should not be used as a key.  It is **very dangerous to mutate a key** hashcode/equals while in use in a map or set. You should cache it on the first call to `hashCode()` so that you do not incur a cost until then unless you are sure you will always need it.

Then change `listToRemoveFromCopy` to be a `Set` so it can be efficiently used in many ways.  You need to do the prior step before this.

**Now you have multiple options.  The most efficient is:**

[**Guava**](https://github.com/google/guava) has a utility function [`Maps.filterKeys`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#filterKeys-java.util.Map-com.google.common.base.Predicate-) which returns a view into a map, and you can create a predicate that works against a `Set` of the items to remove.

```
 val removeKeys = listToRemoveFromCopy.toSet()
 val mapView = Maps.filterKeys(map, Predicates.not(Predicates.in(removeKeys)))
```

But be sure to note some methods on the view are not very efficient.  If you avoid those methods, this will be the top performing option:

> Many of the filtered map's methods, such as size(), iterate across every key/value mapping in the underlying map and determine which satisfy the filter. When a live view is not needed, it may be faster to copy the filtered map and use the copy.

**If you need to make a copy instead, you have a few approaches:**

Use [`filterKeys`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-keys.html) on the map to create a new map in one shot.  This is good if the remove list might be a larger percentage of the total keys.

```
val removeKeys = listToRemoveFromCopy.toSet()
val newMap = map.filterKeys { it !in removeKeys }
```

Another tempting option you should be careful about is the minus `-` operator which copies the full map and then removes the items.  It can use the `listToRemoveFromCopy` as-is without it being a set, but the full map copy might undo the benefit.  So do not do this unless the remove list is a small percentage of keys.

```
val newMapButSlower = map - listToRemoveFromCopy
```

You could pick one model over the other depending on the ratio between map size and remove list size, find a breaking point that works for your "huge".

**Implementing your own view into the map to avoid a copy is possible**, but not trivial (and by that I mean *very complex*).  Every method you override has to do the correct thing at all times (including the map's own `hashCode` and `equals`), and other views would have to be created around the key set and values.  The `entrySet` would be nasty to get right.  I'd look for a pre-written solution before attempting your own (the Guava one above or other).  This zero-copy model would be the most efficient solution but the most code and is what I would do in the same case if "huge" meant significant processing time.  There is a lot that you can get wrong with this approach if you misunderstand any part of the implementation contract.

You could wrap the Guava solution with one that maintains the `size` attribute as items are manipulated and therefore be efficient for that case. You can also write a more efficient solution if you know the original map is read-only.  For ideas, check out the Guava implementation of [FilteredKeyMap](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/e41e8d13f3b1d3101b47df73bb2f582b8cdb51e2/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Maps.java#L2817) and its ancestor [AbstractFilteredMap](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/e41e8d13f3b1d3101b47df73bb2f582b8cdb51e2/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Maps.java#L2695).

**In summary,** likely the caching of your hashcode is going to give you the biggest result for the effort.  Start there.  You'll need it to do even for the Guava approach.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. Caching the hash-calculation sounds really interesting. I will test and profile this. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: apparently caching the hashcode was the fastest of all tested ones :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filterKeys` function. It will iterate map only once

```
val copy = map.filterKeys { it !in listToRemoveFromCopy }
```

Comment: this is slow on a large remove list too.

Comment: filterKeys is depressingly slow. It's about hundred times (!) faster to just iterate over the original map and then copy over matching entries into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Axel's direct answer:

Could calculating the hashcode of a Job be optimised?  If the calculation can't be sped up, could it cache the result?  (There's ample precedent for this, including `java.lang.String`.)  Or if the class isn't under your control, could you create a delegate/wrapper that overrides the hashcode calculation?